# On using Microsoft MAUI Graphic with Skiasharp to create PNG image having memory leak

Tags: memory, memory-leaks

I am using Microsoft Maui graphics library to generate png images in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, after each call and on generating image memory keeps on increasing.

Can anyone suggest for this?

Disposing bitmap, image and canvas also. Still no improvement

Comment: disposing skpaint? show code maybe

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar, if not the same issue, although with just using SkiaSharp on itself. I also use ASP.NET Core 6, but in a dockerised environment under Linux. If you are also using Docker with Linux, this might help you:

I couldn't really find a solution to this problem so I was trying out other graphics-libraries such as Magick.Net (https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET). The problem persisted though. As I searched for a solution I stumbled upon this comment in one of the issues of that repository: https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/issues/707#issuecomment-785351620

Adding "ENV MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_=100000" to the dockerfile of my project basicaly ensures that enough memory is being released again. I now use the SkiaSharp library again and had no problems since.

Comment: Thanks for the update on MichaelK. On setting MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_=100000" is there impact on memory usage of api I mean will api can use only this much of memory,if require more than this , api will crash ?

Comment: Also this issue is in linux only ? In Windows Also memory keep growing checked in debug diagnostic tool